# CSS :after pseudoselector does not consider text clipping

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a menu item as below.[image]

My idea was to have :after for all individual divs and add border radius to :after element in each div to get the curved shape for each menu and position the after using z-index.

But while implementing a text clipping for each menu item  , the :after elements seem to position themselves away from parent div . They seem not to recognise the text is being clipped and take full width of original text.

[Click here for the fiddle highlighting the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/65kc85e7/)

Here is my implementation

```css
.interaction-area {
  height: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
}

.context-item__child {
  height: 40px;
  max-width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.context-item__child:after {
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="interaction-area">
  <div class="context-item__child">T</div>
  <div class="context-item__child">DE FINIBUS BONORUM ET MALO</div>
  <div class="context-item__child">NIHIL IMPEDIT QUO MINUS ID QUOD MAXIME</div>
  <div class="context-item__child">DE FINIBUS BONORUM ET MALORUM</div>
  <div class="context-item__child">NIHIL IMPEDIT QUO MINUS ID QUOD MAXIME</div>
</div>
```

Could you guide me what i am missing to make it work? Or is there a better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'd do this:

```css
.interaction-area {
  height: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
}

.context-item__child {
     height: 40px;
    max-width: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #4286f4;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 0 22px 22px 0;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.context-item__child:last-child {
  
}
.context-item__child span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.context-item__child:after {
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 0;
  top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="interaction-area">
    <div class="context-item__child"><span>T</span></div>
    <div class="context-item__child"><span>DE FINIBUS BONORUM ET MALO</span></div>
    <div class="context-item__child"><span>NIHIL IMPEDIT QUO MINUS ID QUOD MAXIME</span></div>
    <div class="context-item__child"><span>DE FINIBUS BONORUM ET MALORUM</span></div>
    <div class="context-item__child"><span>NIHIL IMPEDIT QUO MINUS ID QUOD MAXIME</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I did was:

- moved the ellipsis down a level
- applied `position:relative` to the menu items so their pseudo-elements would be positioned relative to them
- made each item have the proper border-radius so they could wrap without breaking UI.
- adjusted paddings/margins to the new changes.

Comment: I'd love to know the reason for the down-vote. Happy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Flexbox` for `ul` and pseudo-elements to add that rounded border. You can create half circle with `border-radius` but then you also need to hide part of it with another pseudo-element so that it looks nice when `li` breaks to new line

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  
}
li {
  background: #498FF1;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: white;
}
li:not(:first-child) {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
li:after, li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 100%;
  height: 39px;
  width: 39px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 1;
  background: #498FF1;
}
li:after {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #498FF1;
  border-radius: 0;
  transform: rotate(0) translatex(-20px);
  border: 1px solid #498FF1;
  height: 38px;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `:after` alongside `position:relative` and `flexbox`.

You would need to optimise this a bit more... but I am sure you can handle it

```css
 .interaction-area {
   height: 30px;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: small;
   color: white;
   position: relative; /* position relative */
   display:flex; /* display flex */
   width: auto;
 }
 
 .context-item__child {
   height: 40px;
   max-width: 200px;
   line-height: 40px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-right: 20px; /* adjust padding */
   background-color: #4286f4;
   border-right: 0 solid white;
   border-top: 2px solid white;
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; /* position relative */
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
  .context-item__child:first-child:before { 
  display:none;
  }
 .context-item__child:before { /* changed to next element's before */
   height: 40px;
   width: 30px;
   top: -2px; /* fix for border */
   left:-10px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: #4286f4;
   border-right: 2px solid white;
   border-top: 2px solid white;
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
   border-top-right-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
   content: '';
 }

 .context-item__child:last-child { /* changed to next element's before */
  padding-right: 40px;
 }
 
 .interaction-area:after { /* changed to next element's before */
   height: 40px;
   width: 30px;
   top: -2px;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: #4286f4;
   border-right: 2px solid white;
   border-top: 2px solid white;
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
   border-top-right-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
   content: '';
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="interaction-area">
    <div class="context-item__child">T</div>
    <div class="context-item__child">DE FINIBUS BONORUM ET MALO</div>
    <div class="context-item__child">NIHIL IMPEDIT QUO MINUS ID QUOD MAXIME</div>
    <div class="context-item__child">DE FINIBUS BONORUM ET MALORUM</div>
    <div class="context-item__child">NIHIL IMPEDIT QUO MINUS ID QUOD MAXIME</div>
  </div>
</body>
```